# Identify this wild plant with brilliant scarlet red flowers

Tags: species-identification, botany, flowers

Location is Virginia, USA

They seem to last all summer

[image: wild plant with red flowers]

Comment: Possibly a species of Monarda?  AKA bee balm... https://www.wildflower.org/plants/result.php?id_plant=MODI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like some kind of Lobelia. A close up of the flower itself would be very helpful.

I believe it is a [Cardinal Flower](https://www.wildflower.org/plants/result.php?id_plant=loca2):

> This 1-6 ft. perennial has showy, red flowers in 8 in., terminal spikes. Each flower has three spreading lower petals and two upper petals, all united into a tube at the base. Erect leafy stems, often in clusters, with racemes of flowers resembling flaming red spires. The lower portion of the erect stem is lined with lance-shaped leaves.

Comment: That's it!  Thank you.